# R - Number Unique Vals in Col1 of a Data Table when Col2 > Col3

Tags: r, data.table, unique

SampleTable:

```
ID      Score1      Score2
1       100         88
1       96          94
1       94          95
2       100         100
2       98          94
3       77          88
```

So I want the return value to be 2, since there are 2 unique people who have an instance where Score1 > Score2.

For reproducability :

```
df = data.frame( ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,3), Score1=c(100,96,94,100,98,77), Score2=c(88,94,95,100,94,88) )
ID Score1 S
```

I was thinking

```
length( unique( which( df$Score1 > df$Score2 ) ) )
```

However that returns 3, clearly because it doesn't account for looking for the `df$ID` that is unique, just the number of unique occurences.  How do I account for wanting the unique number of unique `df$ID`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for this in `base` R:

```
length(unique(df$ID[df$Score1 > df$Score2]))
[1] 2
```

Or using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Score1 > Score2, uniqueN(ID)]
```

Or `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(Score1 > Score2) %>% { n_distinct(.$ID) }
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I could not come up with. Thank you very much. I couldn't figure out how to incorporate the $ID with the which statement...turns out, I didn't need to which!

Answer (score 0):

Building up on your code, get `unique` on ID

```
length(unique(df[df$Score1>df$Score2,1]))
```

Comment: don't use column numbers

Comment: @MichaelChirico, why not?

Comment: as a rule, it is not at all robust. getting in the practice of using column numbers can lead to hard-to-detect mistakes when columns are added/deleted/reordered further up in the code at a later date